# How to deploy code to SF instance from your branch?

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, vs-code, git

Can I deploy my git branch to salesforce org?
Currently, I write my code in vscode and deploy it to org using vscode. If it works, I add that code in the git branch and commit, which gets merged later.

Is there a command I can use to deploy my code from the branch itself to org?

Comment: Check out the branch then use `sfdx force:source:push`...

Comment: Git has no such command. But you can make use of any ci/cd tool to automate the flow and use sfdx commands to deploy you code from branch to org.

Comment: @PhilW if I use `sfdx force:source:push` will it **only** deploy the component I am working on, or all the components?

Comment: Push pushes all new metadata files or those that have changed since last push.

Comment: If I work on component A, and meanwhile someone made changes in cmp B. When I push the changes I have made in cmp A, the changes made in cmp B both will also be pushed? Is my understanding correct here?